Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^2\left(\pi\,\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}\right)$ two ways gives different answers
This is the question:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^2\left(\pi\,\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}\right) \qquad n\in\mathbb{I}$$
Below are the two methods. Both methods seem correct to me.

1st Method.src)
\begin{align*}
&\cos^2 \left( n\pi - \pi \sqrt[3]{n^3 + n^2 + 2n} \right) \\
&= \cos^2\left( \pi \left( n - (n^3 + n^2 + 2n)^{1/3} \right) \right).
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
(n^3 + n^2 + 2n)^{1/3} - n
&= n (1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2})^{1/3} - n \\
&= n (1 + \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{2}{3n^2}) - n \\
&\approx \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}
$$ \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{4}. $$

2nd Method.src)
\begin{align*}
\cos^2 \left( \pi \sqrt[3]{n^3 + n^2 + 2n} \right)
= \cos^2\left( n \pi \right)
= 1.
\end{align*}

Please tell the mistakes in 2 methods.

Like you, I initially excluded $n$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n} = n \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2}}
\end{align}
Now we have to approximate the expression $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$ for $x\rightarrow 0$. We use Taylor series for this. The following applies:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^2}{9} + O(x^3)
\end{align}
Now we get the following expression:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2}} &= 1 + \left[\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{2}{3n^2}\right] - \left[\frac{1}{9n^2} + \frac{4}{9n^3} + \frac{4}{9n^4}\right] + O(\tfrac{1}{n^3}) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{3n} + O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})
\end{align}
The expression in your cosine is therefore as follows:
\begin{align}
n\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2}} &= n + \frac{1}{3} + O(\tfrac{1}{n})
\end{align}
If we multiply this by $\pi$, the $n\pi$ term is omitted due to the periodicity of the cosine. Due to $n\rightarrow \infty$ the terms with $O(\tfrac{1}{n})$ disappear. The following then applies:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos^2\left(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}\right) = \cos^2\left(\tfrac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{4} 
\end{align}

But why isn't 1+1/n + 2/n^2 directly 1 as n tends to infinity?

"If we multiply this by $\pi$, the $n\pi$
term is omitted due to the periodicity of the cosine." Can you explain?

@IITASPIRANT Because you still multiply with $n$. Your expression is $n \cdot \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2})}$. If you let $n$ go to infinity, then there is practically an expression $\infty \cdot 0$, which is not clearly defined.

@SineoftheTime $\cos^2(n\pi + x) = \cos^2(x)$

ok, so the periodicity of $\cos^2$

It would be good to explain why their second method is wrong. So that this is a genuine teaching opportunity

I don't understand your comment that when $n$ goes to infinity, $n \cdot \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2})}$ is practically $\infty \cdot 0$. Shouldn't it be $\infty \cdot 1$ instead, which has limit $\infty$?

Please don't answer off-topic solution-verification questions. Doing so violates site polciy.

@peterwhy You are forgetting that the expression is multiplied by $\pi$ and is in cosine. The expression $\pi \cdot n(1 + \epsilon)$ thus becomes $\pi \cdot n\epsilon$ and with $n \rightarrow \infty$ you get $\infty \cdot 0$.

We have $$ {x}-n={x^3-n^3\over x^2+nx+n^2}$$ Substitute $x_n=\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}.$ Then $$n^{-1}x_n=\sqrt[3]{1+n^{-1}+2n^{-2}}\to 1$$ $$x_n-n={n^2+2n\over x_n^2+nx_n+n^2}={1+2n^{-1}\over n^{-2}x_n^2+ n^{-1}x_n+1}\to {1\over 3}$$ Thus $$\cos^2 (\pi x_n)=\cos^2(\pi (x_n-n))\to \cos^2(\pi/3)={1\over 4}$$
Remark Your second solution is wrong. If $x_n\to \infty$ and $y_n\searrow 1,$ then the expression $x_ny_n-x_n=x_n(y_n-1)$ may not tend to $0.$ Its behavior is undeterminate as $\infty\cdot 0.$ In your case $x_n=n$ and $y_n=\sqrt[3]{1+n^{-1}+2n^{-2}}.$

Please don't answer off-topic solution-verification questions. Doing so violates site polciy.

$$   n + \frac{1}{3} \;  < \;  \sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}  \;   < \;    n + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{5}{9n}  $$
$$   n \pi + \frac{\pi}{3} \;  < \; \pi  \sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}  \;   < \;    n \pi + \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{5 \pi}{9n}  $$
when $n$ is even
$$   \frac{1}{2} \;  > \; \cos \, \pi  \sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}  \;   > \;   \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{5 \pi}{9n} \right)  $$
and the final term is $ \frac{1}{2}  \cos \left(  \frac{5 \pi}{9n} \right) - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \sin \left(  \frac{5 \pi}{9n} \right) $
and when $n$ is odd
$$  - \frac{1}{2} \;  < \; \cos \, \pi  \sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}  \; <  - \;   \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{5 \pi}{9n} \right)  $$
.....  and so on.

It would be good to explain why their second method is wrong

@FShrike    Not sure how to put it... I like these two sided inequalities, as I do think the students regard  the limiting operation as some sort of magic,   and I try to remove the mystical. Next, I suspect the $o$  and $O$  symbols don't help them much, just more magic

Please don't answer off-topic solution-verification questions. Doing so violates site polciy.
